# Converting two lists to one dictionary WITHOUT losing order in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following problem.
I have the two following lists:

```
d = ['E', 'T', 'A', 'O', 'I', 'N', 'S', 'H', 'R', 'D', 'L', 'C', 'U', 'M', 'W', 'F','G', 'Y', 'P', 'B', 'V', 'K', 'J', 'X', 'Q', 'Z']

list = ['Q', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'R', 'H', 'S', 'N', 'O', 'X', 'W', 'Z', 'V','B', 'P', 'Y', 'F', 'M', 'U', 'C', 'L', 'D', 'E']
```

and I use the command: rotation=dict(zip(list,d)), to combine these lists. However, I get the following dictionary:

```
dict = {'A': 'N', 'C': 'J', 'B': 'G', 'E': 'Z', 'D': 'Q', 'G': 'I', 'F': 'B', 'I': 'T','H': 'R', 'K': 'O', 'J': 'A', 'M': 'V', 'L': 'X', 'O': 'C', 'N': 'L', 'Q': 'E','P': 'Y', 'S': 'D', 'R': 'H', 'U': 'K', 'T': 'S', 'W': 'M', 'V': 'F', 'Y': 'P','X': 'U', 'Z': 'W'}
```

which is completely out of order. 
Is there a way to properly combine these two lists?
I mean for letter 'E' (the first letter of d) to be mapped with letter 'Q' (the first letter of list) and not with 'Z'. Also 'T' to be mapped with 'I' and so on.

Comment: 1) Dictionaries have no order 2) Stop using Python keywords and type names as your variable names

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered by definition. There is an OrderedDict class in the collections module.

Comment: The reason your code is mapping `E` to `Z` is because the you've passed the arguments to `zip` in incorrect order.

Answer (score 3):

You simply did it backwards.  You want `dict(zip(d, list))` (although don't use `list` as a variable name); you want `(key, value)` tuples.

```
In [67]: d = ['E', 'T', 'A', 'O', 'I', 'N', 'S', 'H', 'R', 'D', 'L', 'C', 'U', 'M', 'W', 'F','G', 'Y', 'P', 'B', 'V', 'K', 'J', 'X', 'Q', 'Z']

In [68]: d2 = ['Q', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'R', 'H', 'S', 'N', 'O', 'X', 'W', 'Z', 'V','B', 'P', 'Y', 'F', 'M', 'U', 'C', 'L', 'D', 'E']

In [69]: letter_map = dict(zip(d, d2))

In [70]: letter_map["E"]
Out[70]: 'Q'

In [71]: letter_map["T"]
Out[71]: 'I'
```

Comment: this gives me E:Q while I  need Q:E, i.e. I need: letter_map["Q"] to return 'E'

Comment: maybe I just need to reverse the list

Comment: @Aribas: your original code does that!  Look at the example you posted-- it contains `'Q': 'E'`.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a list to stored the pairs instead of a dictionary.

```
d = ['E', 'T', 'A', 'O', 'I', 'N', 'S', 'H', 'R', 'D', 'L', 'C', 'U', 'M', 'W', 'F','G', 'Y', 'P', 'B', 'V', 'K', 'J', 'X', 'Q', 'Z']
list = ['Q', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'R', 'H', 'S', 'N', 'O', 'X', 'W', 'Z', 'V','B', 'P', 'Y', 'F', 'M', 'U', 'C', 'L', 'D', 'E']
new_list = []
for (dd,l) in zip(d,list):
    i.append((dd,l))
print new
```

Which outputs

```
[('E', 'Q'), ('T', 'I'), ('A', 'J'), ('O', 'K'), ('I', 'G'), ('N', 'A'), ('S', 'T'), ('H', 'R'), ('R', 'H'), ('D', 'S'), ('L', 'N'), ('C', 'O'), ('U', 'X'), ('M', 'W'), ('W', 'Z'), ('F', 'V'), ('G', 'B'), ('Y', 'P'), ('P', 'Y'), ('B', 'F'), ('V', 'M'), ('K', 'U'), ('J', 'C'), ('X', 'L'), ('Q', 'D'), ('Z', 'E')]
```

Comment: Yeah that is definitely a solution but I need a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {}

for i in range(len(list_a)):
    d[list_a[i]] = list_b[i]
```

where list_a and list_b are your two lists to combine